# Compare column collation between two databases

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a production database and a dev database that apparently have differing collation on one or more columns in certain tables. Is there a way I can script something that will return which columns are different?

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio 2010+?  It has built-in Schema Compare tool which will find all differences in table structure between two databases.

Comment: I don't know if I have the + version available.  Is it not available in the 2010 standard edition?

Comment: I just meant version 2010 or higher (i.e., 2012).  I don't know if it's available in the standard edition, but you can check and see if you have a `Data` menu with option "Schema Compare...".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Red-Gate SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) will highlight collation differences. There are plenty of other alternative tools of various cost and quality, which [I blogged about here](http://madelinebertrand.com/2012/04/20/re-blog-the-cost-of-reinventing-the-wheel/), but I can vouch for the quality of Red-Gate's tool. If this is a one-time thing you can use the trial version.

That said, if the databases are on the same server, or one of the servers has a linked server to the other, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT DevObject  = do.name, DevColumn  = dc.name, DevColl  = dc.collation_name,
       ProdObject = po.name, ProdColumn = pc.name, ProdColl = pc.collation_name
FROM devdb.sys.objects AS do
INNER JOIN devdb.sys.schemas AS ds
  ON do.[schema_id] = ds.[schema_id]
INNER JOIN devdb.sys.columns AS dc
  ON do.[object_id] = dc.[object_id]
INNER JOIN productiondb.sys.objects AS po
  ON do.name = po.name
INNER JOIN productiondb.sys.schemas AS ps
  ON ds.name = ps.name
  AND po.[schema_id] = ps.[schema_id]
INNER JOIN productiondb.sys.columns AS pc
  ON dc.name = pc.name
  AND po.[object_id] = pc.[object_id]
WHERE
  dc.collation_name <> pc.collation_name
  -- AND do.name IN (N't1', N't2', N't3', ...) -- filter certain table names
;
```

If they're on different servers you may need to create a linked server on one and then change the references appropriately to 4-part names, say, `linkedservername.devdb.sys.objects` etc.

Comment: Thanks! I've used the Red-Gate SQL Compare before for comparing missing tables but I didn't realize it could be used for collation differences as well.  Unfortunately I think my trial period expired.  I was really looking for the tsql code.  Thanks again!